# Create multiple tables from distinct attribute category values using Model Builder

Tags: modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, table

[image: parcel map with book values]I've got a shapefile I would like to extract distinct values from an attribute field and have the output as tables based on those values.

The shapefile is made of polygons representing parcels and each parcel is categorized by a "book" value. I can extract a table for each book using the Table Select tool in Model Builder, however, I need to produce a table for each of the dozens of "book" values that make up this shapefile. This is basically a "select by attribute" problem but I will need to sort and produce output in the form of tables. I've attached a pdf of the Layer view and contents to help illustrate the problem.

My question is, what sql expression can I use in the Model Builder Table Select tool that will:

1. Select and sort values based on an attribute field (in this case, by "book")
2. Auto create tables for each category of values (i.e., 200, 209, 235)

I'm open to other model builder tools or methods but the "Table Select" method is the most direct approach, however, I can only create one table at a time - I need to create many in one shot.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Galindo37

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you want your end result to be? Do you essentially want to end up with one row that has the Book ID and another that has all of the values that correspond to that book ID separated by a comma?

Comment: The end result should be a Table with the Book ID and all values associated with that book. For example, a table called "Book200" would contain all record values assoicated with "200", to include book page, number, sub-number and so forth like this: Book200, pg103,no 123,subno 005. Each color in the image I provided represents a region or "book" whereby hundreds of listing are represented within each region. I just need a way to automate my table selection based on the attribute value, in this case, on the attribute field "book"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) option to loop through book classes and make a feature layer, from which you can export your table against.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into creating a model [using iterators](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/ESRI_SECTION1_9A6D07FF69AE4A379CFC9031B128ACFD/). It looks like you can set up the tool to loop through all of the available book ids that you have and then build a model that exports each of those results to a table.

Comment: Do you have an example of the model export to table?